# Add a sum total in a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to add a Total at the bottom and do not seem to comprehend how can I get the syntax to show me the 'Total' at the bottom. I have exhausted my time searching for it online. I need the coalesce snippet because I need to show zeros for the Employees with no Sales. I took a look at this link but I need the *Zero* in the coalesce.

[Add a row for TOTAL in a sql query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211482/add-a-row-for-total-in-a-sql-query-result)

```
select t2.Employee, coalesce(t1."This Week",0) "This Week"
from mytable t2 left outer join
(select case when grouping(Employee) = 1 then 'Total' else Employee end, sum(Sales) "This Week"
from information
where Week >= DATE '01/01/2017' and Week < DATE '01/31/2017'
and LastUpdate >= DATE '01/01/2017' and LastUpdate < DATE '01/31/2017'
group by Employee with Rollup) t1
on t1.Employee = t2.Employee
```

Result:

```
Employee                    This Week 

 Batman                       15
 Penguin                      25
 Joker                        0
 Bane                         5
 Scarecrow                    0
 ------------------->         45
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "with"
LINE 8: group by Employee with Rollup) t1
```

Comment: Change your `Group by` statement to `Group By Employee With Rollup` see if that works

Comment: You are looking for [`ROLLUP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/queries-table-expressions.html).

Comment: Shows an error at With...

Comment: I am looking for anything that will show a Total at the bottom.

Comment: Can you post your update?

Comment: Asked just yesterday: [Use Rollup](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/41601153/add-a-total-at-the-bottom/41601535)

Comment: Thanks @ Musters but I have a subquery here which I need to encompass.

Comment: Where does this `with rollup` come from? I may be mistaken, but in postgres you should use `GROUP BY ROLLUP(employee)`

Comment: That's my bad. I was going for the SQL Server version. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with [`ROLLUP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-table-expressions.html)

```
SELECT coalesce(Employee,'Total'),
       "This Week"
FROM
  (SELECT t2.Employee,
          coalesce(sum(t1.Sales),0) "This Week"
   FROM mytable t2
   LEFT JOIN information t1 ON t1.Employee = t2.Employee
   AND t1.Week >= DATE '01/01/2017'
   AND t1.Week < DATE '01/31/2017'
   AND t1.LastUpdate >= DATE '01/01/2017'
   AND t1.LastUpdate < DATE '01/31/2017'
   GROUP BY rollup(t2.Employee)
  ) x
```

Comment: Thanks vkp for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the outer query. Besides the conditions on Week and LastUpdate do not concern the join operation; you can move them to the WHERE clause (which the PostgreSQL optimizer should do itself anyway, but that way your query is more clear):

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(t2.Employee, 'Total') AS Employee,
  COALESCE(SUM(t1.Sales), 0) AS "This Week"
FROM mytable t2
LEFT JOIN information t1 USING (Employee)
WHERE t1.Week BETWEEN DATE '01/01/2017' AND DATE '01/31/2017'
  AND t1.LastUpdate BETWEEN DATE '01/01/2017' AND DATE '01/31/2017'
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((t2.Employee), ());
```

Comment: Thanks @ Fabian, it throws out an error on using (Employee) saying ERROR:  column "Employee" specified in USING clause does not exist in right table.

Comment: Huh? There is no employee column in your information table? How come the accepted answer did work for you then? :/